# Resize Amazon EC2 volume without AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, resize, volume, snapshot, amazon-ami

I have a server on aws-ec2 with defaulit free tier. How can I increase the size of volume without using an AMI?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Steps which will help you to resize ec2 volume without AMI (Snapshots).

- Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
- Choose Volumes, select the volume to modify, and then choose Actions, Modify Volume.
- The Modify Volume window displays the volume ID and the volume's current configuration, including type, size, and IOPS. You can change any or all of these settings in a single action. Set new configuration values as follows:

> To modify the type, choose a value for Volume Type. 
>   To modify the size, enter an allowed integer value for Size.
>   If you chose Provisioned IOPS (IO1) as your volume type, enter an allowed integer value for IOPS.

- After you have specified all of the modifications to apply, choose Modify, Yes.
- Modifying volume size has no practical effect until you also extend the volume's file system to make use of the new storage capacity.

After then you have to run these command on ec2 terminal

```
ubuntu@ip-192-168-1-26:~$ sudo su
root@ip-192-168-1-26:/home/ubuntu# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            487M     0  487M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   12M   88M  12% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  5.5G  2.0G  74% /
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/999
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
root@ip-192-168-1-26:/home/ubuntu# sudo file -s /dev/xvd*
/dev/xvda:  DOS/MBR boot sector
/dev/xvda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=e6d1a865-817b-456f-99e7-118135343487, volume name "cloudimg-rootfs" (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
root@ip-192-168-1-26:/home/ubuntu# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  16G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
root@ip-192-168-1-26:/home/ubuntu# sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
CHANGED: partition=1 start=16065 old: size=16761118 end=16777183 new: size=33538334,end=33554399
root@ip-192-168-1-26:/home/ubuntu# sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem at /dev/xvda1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 1
The filesystem on /dev/xvda1 is now 4192291 (4k) blocks long.
```

that's command will help you to resize ec2 volume